# Can I access and modify the data in beforeSend when using jQuery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

As the title mentioned, I'm using jQuery.ajax method to post a set of data:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/api',
    method: 'post',
    data: { name: 'dudu', age: 12 },
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        // I want to change the data here.
    }
});
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Couldn't you change the data just before $.ajax? there is no difference.

Comment: @bingjie2680 I want to change it using `$.ajaxSetup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can, the below is an example:

```
this.data = this.data.replace("12", "13");
```

Remember here data is converted into string hence you will have to manipulate the string for your changes.

Comment: And `settings.data` can do, if the data is set.

Comment: Also, data is converted or not depends on if the processData setting is set ture when calling ajax.